# Create scheduler run weekly in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, scheduler

How can we create a scheduler service that run specify time weekly like this:
Start on 6 AM Monday every week.

Thanks in advance.

This is my code for now but it just a repeatly scheduler for a several time. Not what I want:

```
public class KinesisScheduler: IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IKinesisConsumerService _kinesisService;
        private Timer _timer;

        public KinesisScheduler(IKinesisConsumerService kinesisService)
        {
            _kinesisService = kinesisService;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private void DoWork(object state)
        {
            _kinesisService.Get();
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _timer?.Dispose();
        }
}
```

Comment: What have you try so far ?

Comment: For now I just tried with this but it's not what I want:

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Show your code please